# I can't get BundleVersionKey, BundleIdentiferKey in UnitTest

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, testing, xctest

I develop a framework for iOS apps.
I have an unit-test case for testing to get the bundleIdentiferKey, bundleVersionKey.

When I ran the test, It is always failed because Bundle Key is `nil`.

my logic for getting Bundle ID is below.

```
 NSString * package = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleIdentifierKey];


 NSString * version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:(NSString *)kCFBundleVersionKey];
```

I found that those are `nil` only if the unit test case in **my framework source**,
But Not in my **sample app**.

I think It's not a problem because UnitTest Target also has a bundle Identifier, bundle version in info.plist

```
 NSString *version = (__bridge id)CFBundleGetValueForInfoDictionaryKey(CFBundleGetMainBundle(), kCFBundleVersionKey);

 version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

these are not also help to me..

I don't know how I can resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post updates in comments. Edit your question if you have additional information.

Comment: I've done. Thank you.

Comment: @Seungwon, Hello! Have you figured out how to resolve this?

Comment: @FreeNickname Hi, I'm afraid not :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found two potential ways to solve it depending on what exactly you are trying to do.

Replace `[NSBundle mainBundle]` with `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]]` or set the Host Application in your Unit Test target.

Answer (score 0):

To find your UnitTest BundleID (in Build settings) and use un the fallowing:

```
CFBundleRef currentTestBundle = CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier(CFSTR("<<unit.test.bundleID>>"));
```